# How do I count the number of elements in each group?

Tags: linq

How do I get a count of the elements within a particular group?  So in the query below I want to know how many cancelled and active subscriptions each account has.  What I am getting is either 0 or 1, depending on whether they have at least one cancelled or active subscription.

```
from a in Accounts
let subs = (
        from s in Subscriptions.Where(s=>s.AccountId == a.Id) 
        group s by s.Status into bystatus 
        select bystatus
    )
let csubs = subs.Count (s =>s.Key == "Cancelled")
let asubs = subs.Count (s => s.Key == "Active")
orderby a.Name
select new { a.Name,a.AccountNumber, a.Status, ActiveSubscriptionCount = asubs, CancelledSubscriptionCount = csubs  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're aggregating the data **per-account**.  Is that your intention?  If you want the aggregate data across all accounts you could do either...

`var data = // your above code

int activeSubs = data.Sum(x => x.ActiveSubscriptionCount);

int cancelledSubs = data.Sum(x => x.CancelledSubscriptionCount);`

... or ...

`var data = Subscriptions.GroupBy(s => s.Status);

var activeSubs = data.Count(s => s.Key == "Active");

var cancelledSubs = data.Count(s => s.Key == "Cancelled");`

Comment: I want it aggregated per-account.